# What does it mean to have a list of longitudes and a list of latitudes?

Tags: python, latitude-longitude, matplotlib

I am working with matplotlib. And trying to understand what it might mean to have a list of longitudes and a list of latitudes? such as using

```
plt.plot( [longitude list] , [latitude list] )
```

I am working with the state of Colorado with coordinates:

> ```
> north = 41
> south = 37
> east = -(102+3.0/60)
> west = -(109+3.0/60)
> ```

Direction are that:
"Create an outline of the state boundary. To do that we can use matplotlib to plot 5 points,
with 4 lines between them (these are the four boundary points, plus the first boundary point again, to
close the boundary)."

Also, if the set-up is:
plt.plot( [longitude list], [latitude list] )

then the x-axis would be longitude, and the y-axis would be latitude. But wouldn't it be the other way around. longitude being north and south, and latitude being east and west? Or am I mis-understanding. Is longitude the shifting of the vertical lines of longitude, left and right. And latitude the shifting of up and down of the horizontal lines of latitude, up and down.

Not entirely sure what this means.

Comment: Think of them as `xy` coordiantes where longitud is the coordinate along the `x` axis and latitude is the coordinate along the `y` axis. Having these pairs of coordiantes, you can plot your points in a 2 dimensional coordinate system.

Comment: @MarceloVilla thank you. Then latitude is the shifting up and down of the horizontal lines of latitude. And longitude the right and left shifting of the vertical lines of longitude? So then would the list be: longitude =  [-(102+3.0/60),-(109+3.0/60)].........latitude = [41,37]?

Comment: Not sure what it means to plot 5 points, and then 4 lines between, plus the first boundary point again to close the boundary. This confuses me.

Comment: The longitude and latitude coordinates should be single values so you have pairs when you are going to plot them. Your task is to make a box around the state. So think of `(109+3.0/60, 37)` as your lower left corner and `(102+3.0/60, 41)` as you upper-right corner. This way you have to plot lines between the four corners of the box (lower left, upper left, upper right, lower right)

Comment: @MarceloVilla thank you. Trying to draw this out on a piece of paper. Then (-102.05, 41) upper-right corner, (-109.05, 37) lower left corner. Would (-102.05, 37) be the lower-right corner, and (-109.05, 41) the upper left corner? 
Also would these values be assigned into a list of tuple such as:  lons = [(-109.05,37),(-109.05,41)].........lats = [(-102.05,41),(-102.05,37)]

Comment: I think I understand the positioning now: upper-right: (-102.05, 41) to the right -102.05 and up 41. upper-left: (-109.05,41) to the left -109.05 and up 41. And so forth.

Comment: Now just wondering how to group those pairs in the lons and lats list so that they form a rectangle when plotted.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to plot the lines between each of the corners using `matplotlib`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

north = 41
south = 37
east = -(102+3.0/60)
west = -(109+3.0/60)

plt.plot([west, east], [north, north], c='r')
plt.plot([east, east], [north, south], c='r')
plt.plot([east, west], [south, south], c='r')
plt.plot([west, west], [south, north], c='r')
plt.xlim(west-2, east+2)  # x-axis limits
plt.ylim(south-2, north+2)  # y-axis limits
plt.show()
```

The result:

[image]